# Leer un archivo xml en r studio

Tags: xml, rstudio

Me podrían ayudar estoy cargando un archivo xml en r studio sin embargo he intentado varios métodos para que me quede en un data frame pero lo consigo he logrado llegar hasta la imagen adjunta alguien me podria ayudar para convertirlo en data.frame
El código que tengo hasta ahora es

```
b11 <-  xml_children(read_xml("estructura/ESTRUCTURAS/2019/02. FEBRERO/B11/B11_0690074761001_28-02-2019.xml"))
```

y este el modelo de archivo xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando organizar los datos en un marco de datos, pero no sé cómo ajustar correctamente mi código para obtener eso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Christian Espin a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: A tu pregunta le vendría bien 1) El código que tienes hasta ahora 2) El archivo xml 3) una descripción de como quieres a salida.